# Generate HTML documentation using Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode

How to generate a html documentation from `Xcode 8.2` and `Objective C`?

I have written comments in header file in the format mentioned below

```
/*!
@discussion:comments
**/
$ cd /Users/Premmac/Documents/FOXES/Taxiapp
        $ headerdoc2html -o ~/Desktop/Documentation/ Taxiapp

        Documentation will be written to /Users/Premmac/Desktop/Documentation/
        HTML output mode.
        DIR Taxiapp
        No valid input files specified. 

        Usage: headerdoc2html [-dq] [-o <output directory>] <input file(s) or directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
[for latest xcode version (Ex. 8.2.1)](http://www.appcoda.com/documenting-source-code-in-xcode/)

If you are using old version then try this
[for old xcode version](https://www.raywenderlich.com/66395/documenting-in-xcode-with-headerdoc-tutorial)